# Value in each column of table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

May i get help on this, not sure how to achieve this.

I have a table with 11 columns.

column 2 to column 10 is consists of specific attribute and attribute_value.

for eg: Diameter--> DVALUE

```
     Width-- >  WVALUE
```

Resultset should consists of as Result 1| Result2| Result 3...

Result 1, result2 these are equal to the attribute_value column.

I need to know if any data in attribute value column is not valid then the specific attribute should be in output in respective Result column.

for eg:-

```
SKU      ,Diameter  ,DVALUE ,Width  ,WVALUE ,Bolt 1 ,Bolt_1_VALUE   ,Bolt 2 ,Bolt2_VALUE    ,Nut Design ,Nut_Design_VALUE
AR105    ,Diameter  ,68     ,Width  ,10     ,Bolt 1 ,114.3          ,Bolt 2 ,NULL           ,Nut Design ,Acorn
AR105MB  ,Diameter  ,18     ,Width  ,10     ,Bolt 1 ,114.3          ,Bolt 2 ,NULL           ,Nut Design ,Acorn
M8861A   ,Diameter  ,22     ,Width  ,8      ,Bolt 1 ,150.1          ,Bolt 2 ,NULL           ,Nut Design ,Acorn
RAR105M8 ,Diameter  ,18     ,Width  ,8      ,Bolt 1 ,120.7          ,Bolt 2 ,NULL           ,Nut Design ,Biscuit
ZM8865A  ,Diameter  ,18     ,Width  ,8      ,Bolt 1 ,114.3          ,Bolt 2 ,NULL           ,Nut Design ,Acorn
```

The below condition is used to check data in attribute value

Value for diameter should not be greater than 20

Value for width should not be greater than 10

Value for bolt should not be greater than 130

Only value  Acorn is ALLOW in Nut Design

Result

```
Result1 ,Result2,   Result3,    Result4,    Result5
Diameter,'',        '',         '',         ''

'',      '',        '',         '',         ''  

'Diameter','',     'Bolt 1',   '',          ''  

'',       '',       '',        '',          Nut Design


DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
SKU VARCHAR (50),
Diameter VARCHAR (50),
DVALUE VARCHAR (50),
Width VARCHAR (50),
WVALUE VARCHAR (50),
Bolt1 VARCHAR (50),
Bolt_1_VALUE VARCHAR (50),
Bolt2 VARCHAR (50),
Bolt2_VALUE VARCHAR (50),
NutDesign VARCHAR (50),
Nut_Design_VALUE VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @TABLE

SELECT 'AR105'   ,'Diameter'    ,'68'       ,'Width'    ,'10'       ,'Bolt 1'   ,'114.3'            ,'Bolt 2'   ,NULL           ,'Nut Design'   ,'Acorn' UNION ALL
SELECT 'AR105MB','Diameter' ,'18'       ,'Width'    ,'10'       ,'Bolt 1'   ,'114.3 '        ,   'Bolt 2'   ,NULL           ,'Nut Design'   ,'Acorn' UNION ALL
SELECT 'M8861A' ,'Diameter' ,'22'       ,'Width'    ,'8'        ,'Bolt 1'   ,'150.1'            ,'Bolt 2'   ,NULL           ,'Nut Design'   ,'Acorn' UNION ALL
SELECT 'RAR105M8','Diameter'    ,'18'       ,'Width'    ,'8'        ,'Bolt 1'   ,'120.7'            ,'Bolt 2'   ,NULL           ,'Nut Design'   ,'Biscuit' UNION ALL
SELECT 'ZM8865A' ,'Diameter'    ,'18'       ,'Width'    ,'9'        ,'Bolt 1'   ,'114.3'            ,'Bolt 2'   ,NULL           ,'Nut Design'   ,'Acorn'

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

for width we need to check in other table2 and if value present in table 1 and not present in table 2 then it should be in output.

Declare @table2 table
(
Width varchar (50)
)

insert @table2
select '5' union all
select '8' union all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding this but...

```
Select * 
  from table
 where diameter > 20
    or width > 10
    or bolt > 130
```

**Edit:** So based on your comment, my understanding is that you only want to see the values that breach these limits and blanks for all other columns. In that case something like the following will do the trick

```
SELECT SKU, 
       Case when dvalue > 20 then 'Diameter' else '' end,
       Case when dvalue > 20 then DValue else '' end, 
       Case when wvalue > 10 then 'Width' else '' end,
       Case when wvalue > 10 then WValue else '' end,
       Case when bolt_1_value > 130.0 then 'bolt_1_value' else '' end,
       Case when bolt_1_value > 130.0 then bolt_1_value else '' end,
       Case nut_design_Value when 'Acorn' then '' else 'nut_design_Value'  end ,
       Case nut_design_Value when 'Acorn' then '' else nut_design_Value  end 
  FROM @TABLE
 WHERE dvalue > 20
    OR wvalue > 10
    OR bolt_1_value > 130.0
    or nut_design_Value <>  'Acorn'
```

**Edit 2:** So if I understand correctly you want to include rows where the width is greater than 10  **or** where the value in the `wvalue` field does not exist in the second table?  If I have that correct then this should do it for you....

```
SELECT SKU, 
       Case when dvalue > 20 then 'Diameter' else '' end,
       Case when dvalue > 20 then DValue else '' end, 
       Case when wvalue > 10 or t2.Width is null then 'Width' else '' end,
       Case when wvalue > 10 or t2.Width is null then WValue else '' end,
       Case when bolt_1_value > 130.0 then 'bolt_1_value' else '' end,
       Case when bolt_1_value > 130.0 then bolt_1_value else '' end,
       Case nut_design_Value when 'Acorn' then '' else 'nut_design_Value'  end ,
       Case nut_design_Value when 'Acorn' then '' else nut_design_Value  end
  FROM @TABLE t1
  LEFT JOIN @TABLE2 t2 on t1.wvalue = t2.width
 WHERE dvalue > 20
    OR wvalue > 10
    or t2.Width is null
    OR bolt_1_value > 130.0
    or nut_design_Value <>  'Acorn'
```

Comment: Don't forget If it's nut design, then any values other than Acorn should also be flagged

Comment: Thanks amcdermott, but my main problem is the output format. if any attribute value is not meeting criteria , then its respective attribute should display in output.

Comment: i am getting error : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'when'.

Comment: Sorry - just spotted that when I actually tried to run it. Updating now.

Comment: Thank You Very Much  amcdermott.  will it be possible inside case to write subquery to check value present in other table, and if it is 
    available in other table then it should again exclude from output.
    
    for eg:- if table 2 col1 contain 8 and i want to check whether 8 is available for width. and if only 8 appear then blank.
    beacause for few column i need to check to another table (called as table 2 col 1), to check values that breach.

Comment: That sounds a little more complicated but it could probably be achieved by joining to the other table. I think you don't have enough room in a comment to provide sufficient detail.

Comment: Yes  amcdermott. don't have enough room in a comment to provide sufficient detail. any suggestion how we can achieve joining other table. the other table have only that column which need to check. for eg:- if i need to check width in other table. the other table table2 contain width (8,5,3) if any value present in value column other then this, should come in output. Please let me know if its confusing. Thanks Again. :)

Comment: I'd say mark my answer here as the correct one, create another question showing what you have so far (basically the answer I gave and any changes you've made) and then explain what else you want to achieve, the structure of the new table etc...

Comment: Thanks amcdermott.  i have just edited the question with table 2. so for width i need to check if table 1 contain only those value available in table 2. and if not it should be in resultset.  Please help.